# howto copy dynamic framework from static to app level

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNHUI.png)
I want to copy compiled dynamic library from a static library to application level(.app/Frameworks dir) on build time.

How can I do this?

I tried buildphases to copy but it cannot move files upper over the pod/framework dir to app dir also app not sees it if i copy with bin/sh cp -R some.framework ../../

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: seperate everything

Comment: How is this more separated than in a cocoa pod?

Comment: i want to build a seperate universal framework sdk with all embedded frameworks not want to type everytime another pod after that target in pods file. but embedding dynamic in static framework is not posible, app searchs it on runtime and cant find.so crash

Comment: Try to add this to your Podfile: `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Comment: is that works for non pod frameworks ?  because i have embedded a dynamic framework directly on general tab in to my sdk.

Comment: no it doesnt linked it as ....-static in app

Comment: The `:linkage => :static` makes all pods link statically, and then you don't need to move them to make them statically linked. For other frameworks, you will need to ask the vendor for a status library version.